# HTML page click function for Firefox Add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**Scenario:** Add-on detects phone numbers on a web page and highlights it by hyperlink. When user clicks on the number it should open a new pop up window asking to login into a system.

**Problem:**

Unable to open html page on mouse click.Following is the code

**Code**

`main.js`

```
var {data} = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
include: "*",
attachTo: ["top"],

contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-2.1.0.js"),data.url("script.js")]
});
var myPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
contentURL: self.data.url("page.html")
});
myPanel.show();
```

`script.js`

```
 var regex = /\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}/g;

 jQuery.fn.linker = function () {
    //var regex = /\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}/g;
 $(this).contents()
    .filter(function() { return this.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE; })
    .each(function () { $(this).linker(); });
 $(this).contents()
    .filter(function() { return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; })
    .each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith(
            $(this).text().replace(regex,"<a href=\"\">$&</a>")
        );
    });
 };
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('body').linker();

 $( 'a' ).click( function () {
 var href = $(this).text();
    //alert(href);
    
    var tel = regex.test(href);
    if ( tel ) {
        //alert( 'A telephone link was clicked: ');
        href = href.replace(/[(]\d[)]|[. -]/g,'');
        //alert(href);
        //event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr('href'),"popupWindow","width = 600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `var {data}` is a syntax error. Any error messages? Does `alert(href)` display anything? Remove the spaces from the third `window.open` parameter.

Comment: @RoToRa: `var {data}` is not a syntax error, but IDE detects it as a syntax error. `alert(href)` displays the clicked telephone number and removed the space

Comment: Ah, ok. `var {data} = ...` is a destructuring assignment, but it seems Firefox is currently the only browser supporing it. Did removing the spaces help? `window.open` expects an URI not a "telephone number" - unless you mean the `tel:` protocol, but there is no real point in opening that in a popup window, since it's usually handled by an external program.

Comment: @RoToRa: Reg space..nothing happened. Clicking the number should allow point-point a/v communication through browser via a pop up window..thats the idea

Comment: What exactly does his telephone number in the href attribute look like? As I said, `window.open` expects an URI. You can't use a "telephone number" (what ever you exactly mean with that) there. I think you need to simplify the problem (for yourself, but also for us). Write a simple script showing the problem, leaving out all the irrelevant stuff especially the `require`d scripts, since we don't know what that is anyway.

Comment: @RoToRa Here it goes ...I want to implement Click-to-Call functionality like Skype ,Lync but in my case using Jabber SDK for Web.The  `href` variable stores phone number after trimming space,period or hyphen so that the Jabber SDK can initiate A/V communication. At the end main target to achieve is browser based video communication. Hop e its clear now.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. All I can say is: You can't use `window.open` like this. You either need an URI, or not use `window.open`. Maybe you need a use (or write) browser plugin. In any case your problem description is overloaded with irrelevant stuff and you are leaving the relevant out.

Comment: @RoToRa:Ok. I tried using URI, but when I click on the number it opens the software installed on clients PC which is not the result I want, but the main aim is browser-browser communication. I am unable to find  out how to call the plugin when the user clicks on the phone number.

Comment: Since I don't know the plugin, I can't help you there. Have you tried the documentation or support of the plugin?